# Live site problem , please help immediately

Tags: database

We are getting this error in live site.

[image]

Comment: The module `EM_Recentreviewproducts` could be the problem. Try disabling it

Comment: i updated 2 images, please check......

Comment: Looks like permissions are not right. Double check your permissions. var folder is not 777

Comment: looks like the `EM_Recentreviewproducts` module is trying to write debug info to a directory that doesn't exist. It looks as though it's is trying to create the folder but maybe doesn't have permissions to do so...

It maybe that the SQL shown is not the cause. Unfortunately the trace doesn't show the full path of the file attempting to be created.

Comment: we will check it

Comment: we gave 777 permission for var folder, it worked . Thanks @DaveFarthing

Comment: @DigitalPianism you can write your comment as an answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question as well as the answer are quite low quality. Setting full permissions (777) on the var folder is not a solution but a problem! The real reason behind this needs to be found and fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnnaVölkl for commenting on my post. I will try to find the real reason for the problem & I will try to post good questions in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting 777 permissions to the `var` folder should fix your problem.